# How do I repair or replace this fridge water line connector?

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator

I had to take the doors off my refrigerator to move it through a doorway. I put everything back together, but the part (picture below) that connects the freezer door's water dispenser to the fridge's water supply now leaks when I try to dispense water.

[image: connects the freezer door's water dispenser to the fridge's water supply]

What is this part called?

Is there a trick to reattaching this piece that would prevent the leak?

If I've damaged the piece, where should I find a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that piece called a [Water Connector Union Fitting](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-fitting-water-connector-4373559-ap2973545.html) and a [Tubing Coupler](http://www.repairclinic.com/vwo10/Shop-For-Parts/a4c23/Refrigerator-Hose-Tube-Fitting-Parts).

Verify the size of the tubing, but if it's the normal 5/16" to 1/4" it should be easy to get a replacement at any larger hardware store, such as [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Watts-5-16-in-O-D-x-1-4-in-O-D-Plastic-Coupling-PL-3016/204464263).  The ones I've seen (that look just like yours) don't require any tools, other than [possibly a blade to cut a bit of the tubing off at the end if it's calcified - you just insert the tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u206oYXQ0KE).

You might also check to see if your tube just got pulled out a bit - it's possible it doesn't require replacement.

Comment: The part name was exactly what I needed to find a video (which I added to your answer) showing how to connect--nothing to it. Thank you!